# Google Drive SDK Push Notification : differentiate file open and file change event

Tags: jakarta-ee, google-drive-api, google-apps

I am working on ***Google Drive SDK Push Notification***, I am getting push notification on my callback `servlet`.
Whenever i *change or open file(drive file)* i gets push notifications, from all this notification i am unable to fix which is `File Open` and `File Change event`.

Please help me to sort out this problem.

Comment: @SGC i am checking "kind":"drive#changes" parameter, but for File Open and File update/changes i am getting same "kind":"drive#changes".

Comment: @SGC and one more i am getting same X-Goog-Resource-URI for open and change like X-Goog-Resource-URI  value : https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/changes?includeDeleted=true&includeSubscribed=true&maxResults=100&alt=json

Comment: I am bit confused. Let me make it clear. File.watch notifies you when there is change in the file, not for file open. Changes.watch, notifies you when there is change in your drive. Check this link https://developers.google.com/drive/web/push for example notification. Also, you can see here X-Goog-Resource-URI is not same for file watch and changes watch.

Comment: @SGC let me check whole things once again. I will let you know.

Comment: @SGC all things clear for me. But i need to capture file open and file close event, How can i do this any suggestion ?